# C++ scanning process ids using the command prompt with tasklist

Tags: c++, cmd, tasklist, pid

I'm trying to use c++ to scan in the processes shown in the command prompt of windows when you type in tasklist. 
I haven't have the whole code ready but would like help in trying to read in the processes.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can redirect the standard output, orrrr you can use winapi =)

List of functions to do with processes:
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847.aspx

EnumProcesses function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use PSAPI to do this. You may need to add psapi.lib to your library dependencies.

You can use `EnumProcesses` to fill an array with the IDs of all running processes. You can then use `OpenProcess` with the IDs in your array to retrieve a handle to each running process, then pass the handle to the relevant functions, such as `QueryWorkingSet` to get information about each process.

You can most likely find examples on the MSDN, if you need more help.